# regexp to search and replace any string that starts from a keyword

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Hi want a create a regexp that takes below string and masks all ID at all position that starts from "dream".

```
 s = """Cli house create --house-id dream1.house.hc1.area.aaaaaaaah454432fg7zf5h2ufqxvfhzqokkaufgf5znua36p4puwnog7akcq --zip-code 123456 --sub-zip-id dream1.zip.zc1.area..aaaaaaaawjdrauwdwzn4kfsma7bomq26l3zjeqmx6qsgihhr4kadmbgngxlq --type victorian"""
```

and converts it to

```
s = """Cli house create --house-id dream1.house.hc1.area.<ID> --zip-code 123456 --sub-zip-id dream1.zip.zc1.area..<ID> --type victorian"""
```

s = re.sub(r"(dream\w*.+)(?= *.)(.+)", "\1", s)

but it only works if ID is at end i.e

```
dreamCli house create --house-id dream1.house.hc1.area.aaaaaaaah454432fg7zf5h2ufqxvfhzqokkaufgf5znua36p4puwnog7akcq
```

an id will always in in this format

dream< digit >.< string >.< string >.< string > ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match

```
(\bdream\S*\.)\S*
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\bdream\S*\.` A word boundary, match `dream` followed till the last dot whithout matching whitespace chars,
- `)` Close group
- `\S*` Match 0+ non whitespace char (Match what follows without matching whitespace chars)

And replace with the capturing group followed by `<ID>`

```
\1<ID>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lP6JNE/1)

**Example code**

```
import re

regex = r"(\bdream\S*\.)\S*"
test_str = "Cli house create --house-id dream1.house.hc1.area.aaaaaaaah454432fg7zf5h2ufqxvfhzqokkaufgf5znua36p4puwnog7akcq --zip-code 123456 --sub-zip-id dream1.zip.zc1.area..aaaaaaaawjdrauwdwzn4kfsma7bomq26l3zjeqmx6qsgihhr4kadmbgngxlq --type victorian"
result = re.sub(regex, r"\1<ID>", test_str)
print(result)
```

Output

```
Cli house create --house-id dream1.house.hc1.area.<ID> --zip-code 123456 --sub-zip-id dream1.zip.zc1.area..<ID> --type victorian
```